# Manage permission on branch level in bitbucket

Tags: .net-core, bitbucket, versioning

I am new to bit bucket, using this for managing code versions,
When i add new member to user group, at the time of permission assignment either read or either write
or only Admin is available.

[image]

I want to have user both read and write permission so they can pull and push code into repo, but not the admin right.

Can someone suggest me how to configure this and also let me know if there is any knowledge mismatch in this statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you choose "Write," it will give read and write permissions, so that's probably the option you want.